# Unittest in org source code

Tags: org-mode, python

Upon working in org doc with source code, I want to do unittest whithin

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session my :export none :results output
  import unittest

  def square(n):
      return n ** 2

  class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_a(self):
          check = square(3)
          self.assertEqual(check, 9)

  unittest.main()        

#+END_SRC
```

It reported errors

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Process my not running")
  process-send-string(#<process my> "\n")
  comint-send-string(#<process my> "\n")
  comint-simple-send(#<process my> "")
  comint-send-input(nil t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1913625>)()
  #f(compiled-function (send-wait body) #<bytecode 0x1913675>)(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1913625>) "__org_babel_python_fname = '/tmp/babel-B1lTSa/python-ZsirER'; __org_babel_python_fh = open(__org_babel_python_fname); exec(compile(__org_babel_python_fh.read(), __org_babel_python_fname, 'exec')); __org_babel_python_fh.close()")
  org-babel-python-evaluate-session("*my*" "import unittest\n\ndef square(n):\n    return n ** 2\n\nclass MyCase(unittest.TestCase):\n    def test_a(self):\n        check = square(3)\n        self.assertEqual(check, 9)\n\nunittest.main()        \n" output ("replace" "output"))
  org-babel-python-evaluate("*my*" "import unittest\n\ndef square(n):\n    return n ** 2\n\nclass MyCase(unittest.TestCase):\n    def test_a(self):\n        check = square(3)\n        self.assertEqual(check, 9)\n\nunittest.main()        \n" output ("replace" "output") nil)
  org-babel-execute:python("import unittest\n\ndef square(n):\n    return n ** 2\n\nclass MyCase(unittest.TestCase):\n    def test_a(self):\n        check = square(3)\n        self.assertEqual(check, 9)\n\nunittest.main()        \n" ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace" "output") (:result-type . output) (:results . "replace output") (:exports . "code") (:cache . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:tangle . "no") (:session . "my") (:export . "none")))
  org-babel-execute-src-block(nil ("python" "import unittest\n\ndef square(n):\n    return n ** 2\n\nclass MyCase(unittest.TestCase):\n    def test_a(self):\n        check = square(3)\n        self.assertEqual(check, 9)\n\nunittest.main()        \n" ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "output" "replace") (:result-type . output) (:results . "output replace") (:exports . "code") (:export . "none") (:session . "my") (:tangle . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no")) "" nil 17321 "(ref:%s)"))
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
  command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

What's the problem?

The problem was solved by setting 'exit= False'

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session test  :export none :results output
  import unittest


  def square(n):
      return n ** 2


  class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_a(self):
          check = square(3)
          self.assertEqual(check, 9)


  unittest.main(exit=False)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: .
: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
: Ran 1 test in 0.000s
: 
: OK
```

Comment: org-babel saves the python code in a temp file, opens the file and then does `exec(compile(__org_babel_python_fh.read(), __org_babel_python_fname, 'exec'))` - for some reason, that seems to kill the interpreter: when I execute that last command in the python3 interpreter, the test is run, it produces its output and then the interpreter exits and I'm back in the shell: not sure what is going on.

Comment: You might want to report this to the [org-mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).

Comment: `unittest.main(exit=False)` is a decent a solution @NickD

Comment: That's a very good solution!